# A c# JavaScriptSerializer serialized string has backslashs that cause problems in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, javascriptserializer, jsonserializer

I have line of c# code in ASP.NET MVC view that

```
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
```

If I debug this string is

```
"{\"Age\":14}"
```

So when I assign this string to my javascript code, it fails

```
JSON.parse('@json');
```

The message is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're using MVC3, atleast, so try using:

```
JSON.parse( @Html.Raw(json) );
```

That spits out a HtmlString type, so instead System.String, you could make the type for `json` into an HtmlString. Also, you might want to look into the [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library which is just better (also the default in MVC4, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

It's not the backslashes that causes the problem, it's the HTML encoding. Actually there isn't any backslashes at all in the string, that's only how the debugger displays a string with quotation marks in it.

The `@` command will HTML encode the string, so the code will look like this:

```
JSON.parse('{&quot;Age&quot;:14}');
```

Use the `Raw` method to output the string without HTML encoding:

```
JSON.parse('@Raw(json)');
```